# What is a good way to display a ranked list in a table cell?

Tags: tables, lists, visual-design

I have a set of metrics to fill each row of a table. And each metric has some factors, usually, there are about 10-20 factors for one metric and they are ranked by their importance as well. Now I would like to display these ranked factors in a table cell. I am quite confused as to a good way to display them, by indicating their ranks? Just a plain text? A list in a cell with the ability of accordion? or ...

For example:

## metric name     |     factors

## Metric A        |    f1, f2, f3....

## Metric B        |    f2,f3,f4,f1...

## Metric C        |    f2,f4,f6....

Comment: Are the rankings always in series, like 1, 2, 3, ...? And why do the factors have to be in a table cell?

Comment: @JOG, this is the requirement from the spec.  Besides, the rankings can be any kind, according to their metric.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the 'importance' rank of the metrics. Is this a quantifiable value that can be sorted? Is there more than one way to sort them?

Comment: @MichaelLai, the factor can be a string with some value, which is computed by some algorithm. Then the factors of one metric can be sorted(descending) by their values.

Comment: Perhaps the question needs a little more details and an example for you to get the answers you look for.

Answer (score 1):

If you do need to keep the factors in a cell, and the ranking is in series, like 1, 2, 3, and so on; then **just ordering them** is probably one of the best ways to compress information like that. You could additionally put a text somewhere (table header perhaps) **"Most important first"**, if needed.

If the ranking of the factors are of greater importance you might want to provide a way to **Open** or **Zoom** in on them. For example, clicking the cell might take you to a new page, or open a window, depending on your platform.

If you do provide a more spacious area for the factors to be displayed, you should use the height by giving each factor a row, and sort the rows.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRY3s2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are really trying to show, but I assume that you want to highlight how different metrics put emphasis on different factors, so here's one particular approach. Of course, it is probably not suitable if you have a lot of different factors, but if you can provide more details then I am sure the community will be able to give you some ideas.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I am wanting to find a way to display the ranked factors  for each metric properly. So we can ignore the ranking relations for different metrics. Currently, I am just using a plain text to display them in a cell, such as Factor 1, Factor 2, Factor3....